# Error while using migrate in Django to postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

I am using postgresql as database for my django project and it is showing me that i don't have permission to even create the data tables when I run migrate command.

Error:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "django_migrations" ("id" bigint NOT NULL PRIMA...
                     ^
)
```

My code:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "knapds",
        "USER": "admin",
        "PASSWORD": "password",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "PORT": "5432",
    }
}


CREATE DATABASE knapds;

CREATE USER knapds WITH PASSWORD 'password';

ALTER ROLE system SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';

ALTER ROLE system SET default_transaction_isolation TO 'read committed';

ALTER ROLE system SET timezone TO 'Africa/Johannesburg';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE knapds TO system;

\q
```

Postgresql version is 15.4

This is result after\l knapds

[image]

Comment: 1) In `psql` do `\l knapds` and **add the result as update to question text**. 2) Postgres version? **Add to question also**

Comment: I am grateful for your guidance. Thanks to your assistance, I have successfully resolved the issue by changing the owner to the system. I got to know that was the problem because of you.

Comment: 1) Postgres 15 [Release Notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/release-15.html): *Remove PUBLIC creation permission on the public schema* 2) You are connecting as `admin` and I don't see that user having any permissions(Access privileges) on `knapds`. 3) `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE` is probably not what you think it  is. Read [Grant privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ddl-priv.html) for what you are actually granting.

Comment: shouldn't you log in as `system`, not as `admin`?